# JTable sorting rows in Java 1.5

Tags: java, jtable

Is there a simple way to sort rows in a JTable with Java 1.5 (`setAutoCreateRowSorter` and `TableRowSorter` appear to be Java 1.6 features)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting in Java 1.5 is only possible via libraries.

E.g. use the JXTable mentioned from Kaarel or VLTable from [here](http://www.vlsolutions.com/en/documentation/articles/jtable/index.php).

Another good library is [glazedlists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/)

which is also used in the Spring Rich Client project.

There are even ways to use [Glazed Lists with JXTable](http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/documentation/swingx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `JXTable` from the [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org) project, see e.g.

- [SwingLabs: How to Use the SwingX JXTable: Sorting Rows](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/SwingLabsSwingXJXTableHowTo#RowSorting)

Answer (score 0):

JXTable requires a big package, and is difficult to get the right version for.  (no higher than version 1.0 for Java 1.5).

Try instead TableSorter.java.  Get it at:

http://ouroborus.org/java/2.1/TableSorter.java

And insert it in your project.

Now you wrap your tableModel in an instance of TableSorter, and instert that into the JTable.  TableSorter acts as a "go-between" the JTable-instance and your tableModel.

Use it something like this  (code untested):

```
JTable myTable = new JTable();
TableSorter mySorter = new TableSorter(myTableModel, myTable.getTableHeader());
myTable.setTableModel(mySorter);
```

You can set sprting programmatically like this:

```
mySorter.setSortingStatus(0,TableSorter.ASCENDING);
```

Try tweeking `MouseHandler.mouseClicked()` to get it to skip the NOT_SORTED option in the clicking order, and mess with renderers for e better column header and placing and visibility of triangle.