# JavaFX Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, javafx

Im in the verge of starting a new RIA development. We've been using Flex/Flash for the last 2 years but we were considering using a more OS approach so we though giving JavaFX a try since it seams the only solid option available. However after a couple of days of research we found out that there is not such thing as a datagrid for it, at least not in the core API. For those unfamiliar with Flex, a Datagrid is a component that allows you to display a collection of data in column-row layout (much like a HTML Table on steroids). The beauty of it is that you only need to worry about the data itself as the component does pretty much the rest (sorting, column dragging, etc).

Im afraid to ask... but is there something slightly similar for JavaFX?

We require nothing as fancy as Flex Datagrids/AdvancedDatagrids, we only require a easy, straight forward way to display grids of data that are able to have a little of interaction like clicking, sorting and that are able to display images, buttons, etc. without having to download a ton of different jars.

If there isn´t something out there... This would be a shot in the back of the head to the idea of giving javaFx the chance to compete with flash on our project (which is sad).

I really cant believe the SUN people didnt include something like this on the core API...

Comment: We are recently examining the CRUDFx library, it looks promising so far Im only concerned about the poor documentation available for it. Most of the library's blog is written in Russian =D

Comment: We also found the JFXtras 0.6 library, if some one could provide some comments on their own experience using either of the two libraries it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't considering AIR?

Comment: AIR doesn't run in Mobile devices as it requires AIR run-time engine to execute, that's basically why. Besides, one of the reasons we decided not to use any Adobe Technology is because of that and the fact that you require at some point a Flex Builder License for that (there are OS alternatives but they suck big time if compared, like Flash Develop).

Comment: Has someone used Apache Pivot on mobile devices?

Comment: Maybe this wasn't the case in 2010, but AIR definitely runs on mobile now... including those tyrannically controlled Apple devices - I think it's even enforced by court decision now after Apple tried to block it.  Hah...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no datagrid you can use JTable for that. Such a thing should be available in the next release of JavaFX I think. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591610/jtable-sorting-rows-in-java-1-5/1622277#1622277) for more information about available JTable implementations. You mentioned the JFXtras project with that you are able to embed those Swing components into JavaFX.

There are external companies selling such a component. E.g. do a web search or [look here](http://www.zfqjava.com/features/componentpack/index.html)

For apache pivot you should ask them directly for the pros and cons; they are very responsive and honest.

Comment: Times have changed apparently, this is called a "TableView" in JFX now.