# TableRowSorter and RowFilter in java 1.4

Tags: java, rowfilter, tablerowsorter

I'm actually in a middle of a small problem. I have discovered that TableRowSorter and RowFilter are not included in Java 4. All of our clients are using Java 1.4.2_08 and it's not convenient for us to install java 6 on their machines. Is there by any chance, a way in which I can use the TableRowSorter, and the RowFilter classes, by using JDK 1.4.2_08?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using regex to parse the entered search criteria in my JTables, and creating a new ArrayList to store the results. After that, I did the data binding for my JTable's model with the newly created ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591610/jtable-sorting-rows-in-java-1-5) offers some answers with alternative libraries for sorting tables. If they require Java 1.5 you should be able to use [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) to make them compatible with Java 1.4. It's probably not a trivial effort to get it working and support it though. I'd push for upgrading the clients to 1.6 even though it's not convenient. There are plenty of other benefits to upgrading anyhow, particularly for security fixes.

Comment: Thanks a lot whiteFang, I will try what you have suggested. I know that upgrading would be of a great benefit, but still, the company where I work think that it's more convenient for them to keep the actual Java setup.

Comment: I tried what has been suggested, but I had a lot of problems at runtime. Does anyone have another suggestion?